# I will get this error No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy' even I installed flask_sqlaclcheny?

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I installed SQLAlchemy on my venv but It still give me error :

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
I activate my venv. I runned my flask on app.py and then I did python3 create.py
These two lines are in models.py file.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

```
from flask import Flask
from models import *
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)
def main():
    db.create_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        main()
```

```
 $ pip3 list
Package          Version
---------------- -------
click            7.1.2
Flask            1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.4
itsdangerous     1.1.0
Jinja2           2.11.3
MarkupSafe       1.1.1
pip              21.0.1
setuptools       53.0.0
SQLAlchemy       1.3.23
Werkzeug         1.0.1
wheel            0.36.2
(venv)
```

Comment: I solved it. If you installed sql_alchemy but you are still getting error, check your python version. If you have multiply of version unstill all python and clean pip cash and then install just one version of python. These kind of package should install outside of virtualenv. python3 ---> pip3 install .....

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have :

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

in your main file.

Then import:
`from main  import db`
in your models file.

I believe I have encountered this error in the pas although dont exactly remember how I resolved it.

Comment: This has worked for me in the past although i used a python package, with __init__.py as my main file

Comment: I'm still getting error. I just add everything to my main file but it gives me error.